# Deployed my app to EC2 using Capistrano, where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano

So I have a rails app and am deploying to ec2. I successfully did cap deploy:setup, cap deploy:check, and cap:deploy.  I then tried to access the url, but I'm not actually sure where my app is or if there are more steps.  I tried accessing http://xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/var/www/highlandsfacebookart, but got nothing.

Here is my deploy.rb

```
set :application, "highlandsfacebookart"
set :repository,  "repository-url"

set :user, 'ec2-user'
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}#"
#set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/highlandsfbkey.pem)
set :scm, "git"

# set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "xxx.compute.amazonaws.com"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
role :db,  "xxx.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but have you configured your instance to serve your website using a web server like Nginx? Set it up so it's listening on port 80 and pointing to the correct folders. Nginx integration in Capistrano is possible I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your instances are running when you're accessing EC2's console on `aws.amazon.com/console`? (Sorry, I wish I had enough reputation to make this a comment)

Comment: You might also have to set TCP rules (through the console) to allow incoming traffic and from what IP addresses.